# Python: Requests won't POST if I have punctuation in my data

Tags: python, rest, post, python-requests, hipchat

I have a `small_file.txt` file that contains:

```
1asdfaksdjfhlaksjdhflkjashdflkjhasldkjfhlaksdfhasdf:
2asdfaksdjfhlaksjdhflkjashdflkjhasldkjfhlaksdfhasdf:
3asdfaksdjfhlaksjdhflkjashdflkjhasldkjfhlaksdfhasdf
4asdfaksdjfhlaksjdhflkjashdflkjhasldkjfhlaksdfhasdf:
```

Notice the colons at the end, they are just regular strings.

When I try to send it using `python requests` it doesn't work. For some reason, it waits for the first line with a colon and then sends all the lines starting from there. So for example, in the file above, it will `POST` only:

```
3asdfaksdjfhlaksjdhflkjashdflkjhasldkjfhlaksdfhasdf
4asdfaksdjfhlaksjdhflkjashdflkjhasldkjfhlaksdfhasdf:
```

How can I fix this issue? I'm not sure what is going on.

Here is a simple version of my code:

```
import requests
import sys
import json
import os


token                    = 'nVQowAng0c'
url                      = "https://api.hipchat.com/v2/room/test_room/share/file"
headers                  = {'Content-type': 'multipart/related; boundary=boundary123456'}
headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token


filepath = 'small_file.csv'
data     = open(filepath, 'rb').read()

payload = """\
--boundary123456
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="metadata"
--boundary123456
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="file"; filename="{0}"
{1}
--boundary123456--\
""".format(os.path.basename(filepath), data)


r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
r.raise_for_status()
```

When I try to send something like a `.csv` file with a timestamp on every row, nothing will get sent because each row has a colon.

Comment: Why are your manually formatting the multipart/form-data payload? Just use `files` instead of `data`.

Comment: Your `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` part is entirely empty.

Comment: `requests` doesn't do anything special with that data. It works just fine when I replace the URL with `http://httpbin.org/post`, which echoes back what is posted.

Comment: Ah, HipChat wants a `multipart/related` mimetype, lets see if requests-toolbelt can handle this for you instead.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for posting, I am trying to keep up. So do you think I should try the `files` thing?

Comment: No, `files` will send `multipart/form-data`, you need `multipart/related` (thanks HipChat, for not sticking to something more widespread that'd have sufficed).

Comment: I see, so what can I try?

Comment: Your immediate error is that there is no newline between headers and file content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate error is that you misencoded the MIME multipart elements. Each part has **two** sections, headers and contents, with a double newline between. Yours is missing the second newline, add it in:

```
payload = """\
--boundary123456
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="metadata"

--boundary123456
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="file"; filename="{0}"

{1}
--boundary123456--\
""".format(os.path.basename(filepath), data)
```

I'd not manually build the contents, but re-purpose the [`requests-toolbelt` project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-toolbelt) to let you upload your data in a streaming fashion:

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder


class MultipartRelatedEncoder(MultipartEncoder):
    """A multipart/related encoder"""
    @property
    def content_type(self):
        return str(
            'multipart/related; boundary={0}'.format(self.boundary_value)
        )

    def _iter_fields(self):
        # change content-disposition from form-data to attachment
        for field in super(MultipartRelatedEncoder, self)._iter_fields():
            content_type = field.headers['Content-Type']
            field.make_multipart(
                content_disposition='attachment', 
                content_type=content_type)
            yield field


m = MultipartRelatedEncoder(
    fields={
        'metadata': (None, '', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
        'file': (os.path.basename(filepath), open(filepath, 'rb'), 'text/csv'),
    }
)

headers['Content-type'] = m.content_type

r = requests.post(url, data=m, headers=headers)
```

I've adapted the [`requests_toolbelt.MultipartEncoder` class](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uploading-data.html#requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder.MultipartEncoder) to emit a `multipart/related` data stream rather than a `multipart/form-data` message.

Note that I pass in the *open file object*, and not the file data itself; this because the `MultipartEncoder` lets you *stream* the data to the remote server, the file doesn't have to be read into memory in one.

You probably want to pass in actual JSON data in the `metadata` part; replace the empty string in the `(None, '', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'` tuple with a valid JSON document.

Comment: Do you know what I can do if I wanted to send an excel file: I get an error like `''charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 639: character maps to <undefined>'` UPDATE: Nevermind, it works. Thanks again.

Comment: When I try to send a file this way, it works. The only issue is that the file that is send has the newlines as strings in the uploaded file. So when sombody downloads the file they get a file with one string like `1asdfaksdjfhlaksjdhflkjashdflkjhasldkjfhlaksdfhasdf:\r\n2asdfaksdjfhlaksjdhflkjashdflkjhasldkjfhlaksdfhasdf:\r\n3asdfaksdjfhlaksjdhflkjashdflkjhasldkjfhlaksdfhasdf\r\n4asdfaksdjfhlaksjdhflkjashdflkjhasldkjfhlaksdfhasdf:\r\n` Additionally, when I try to send an `.xlsx` file, I get an error like [this](http://imgur.com/a/xEs7p).

Comment: @user1367204: Are you using Python 2 or 3? In Python 3, your data is uploaded as a *representation*, with `b'` and the start and `'` at the end; you'd have to define your string format as a bytestring instead and use `%` formatting. Best not go that way at all however, and use the `requests-toolbelt` encoder I added.

Comment: I am using python 3, and I already combined your requests-toolbelt code into the code.

Comment: @user1367204: then the data is correctly uploaded; something else is going wrong *elsewhere* if your data comes back with literal newlines. The `requests-toolbelt` encoder sends the raw file data, correctly wrapped.

Comment: Do you think that the `'file': (os.path.basename(filepath), open(filepath, 'rb'), 'text/csv')` line would still work with an `.xlsx` file?

Comment: @user1367204: absolutely, but adjust the mimetype to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

Comment: @user1367204: perhaps use the [`mimetypes` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html) to supply the mimetype for the file you upload.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the combined code from @Martijn Pieters:

```
# do this:
#     pip install requests_toolbelt

from os                import path
from sys               import exit, stderr
from requests          import post
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder


class MultipartRelatedEncoder(MultipartEncoder):
    """A multipart/related encoder"""
    @property
    def content_type(self):
        return str('multipart/related; boundary={0}'.format(self.boundary_value))

    def _iter_fields(self):
        # change content-disposition from form-data to attachment
        for field in super(MultipartRelatedEncoder, self)._iter_fields():
            content_type = field.headers['Content-Type']
            field.make_multipart(content_disposition = 'attachment',
                                 content_type        = content_type)
            yield field




def hipchat_file(token, room, filepath, host='api.hipchat.com'):

    if not path.isfile(filepath):
        raise ValueError("File '{0}' does not exist".format(filepath))


    url                      = "https://{0}/v2/room/{1}/share/file".format(host, room)
    headers                  = {'Content-type': 'multipart/related; boundary=boundary123456'}
    headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token



    m = MultipartRelatedEncoder(fields={'metadata' : (None, '', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
                                        'file'     : (path.basename(filepath), open(filepath, 'rb'), 'text/csv')})

    headers['Content-type'] = m.content_type

    r = post(url, data=m, headers=headers)

if __name__ == '__main__:

    my_token = <my token>   
    my_room  = <room name>    
    my_file  = <filepath>

    try:
        hipchat_file(my_token, my_room, my_file)
    except Exception as e:
        msg = "[ERROR] HipChat file failed: '{0}'".format(e)
        print(msg, file=stderr)
        exit(1)
```